# How can I replace a DOMNode with a DOMNodeList in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, xmldom

Up until now I've been able to replace nodes pretty easily because I've only needed to replace them 1:1 and because they were only text. I was using something like this:

```
$element->parentNode->replaceChild($element->ownerDocument->createTextNode($value),$element);
```

The problem now is that I need to accept strings that may or may not include some HTML. For instance I can no longer use `createTextNode()`  with the string:

```
This is some <span style="font-weight:bold;"></span> text.
```

because I'll end up with a mix of html entities in my actual html. Nor can I do this one:

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

I've revised my code to the following, the first part creates a new dom node by importing the text/html mix with a wrapper I can use to pull it back out as a node with, and the second part imports the new `<fubar>` DOMNode, and replaces the original node with it:

```
$temp = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$temp->loadHTML('<fubar id="replacement">'.$val.'</fubar>');
$replacement = $temp->getElementById('replacement');

$replacement = $element->ownerDocument->importNode($replacement, TRUE);
$element->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement,$element);
```

The problem that remains, which I can't get my head around, is that the document now contains all of the new node *including* the `<fubar>` element, but it's the only way to do the 1:1 replacement because `replaceChild()` requires the parameter to be a DOMNode, so I can't use the nodes DOMNodeList of children directly.

**What is the easiest solution to either remove the `<fubar>` node but keep its child nodes (the actual content I want), or to replace the original node with multiple nodes directly?**

---

**EDIT:** The complete intention would be to take:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Opening content....<placeholder>REPLACE_ME_FIRST</placeholder></p>
        <placeholder>REPLACE_ME_SECOND</placeholder>
        <p>Closing content....</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

then replace the `<placeholder>REPLACE_ME_FIRST</placeholder>` with...

```
This is some <span style="font-weight:bold;"></span> text.
```

and replace the `<placeholder>REPLACE_ME_SECOND</placeholder>` with...

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Resulting in:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Opening content....This is some <span style="font-weight:bold;"></span> text.</p>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
        <p>Closing content....</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and in my original question, in the code example, `$element` would represent the `<placeholder>` node.

Comment: You will have to import the child nodes individually.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to figure out a solution to that too as a first attempt, but there only seems to be `insertBefore()` and no `insertAfter()` so I couldn't do it in series.... at that point my brain went to mush.  Any suggestion as to the best way to accomplish that?  Feel free to add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @CBroe wouldn't that only work if this were the only (or last) node in a parent, the issue is the node I'm replacing may be in the middle of a long list of other nodes, so `appendChild` would add it to the end of that list rather than in the position of the actual replacement.

Comment: Well you could f.e. loop through the new nodes in inverse order, and insert the current one before the replacement element each time, so they “stack up” above it in the DOM tree in original order … and afterwards, you remove the _replacement_ element. Or you append them into a `DOMDocumentFragment` before in original order, and then replace the _replacement_ element with that.

Comment: Do you have an example for `$val` so we can recreate that?

Comment: @kaiser There are two examples of $val in the question, `This is some...` and `<p>Para....`.  Both would result in multiple child nodes which will only work with `replaceChild` if they have a single node parent, which is why I wrap them in the `<fubar>` tag.

Comment: @kaiser added a full example of intent to question.

Comment: @CBroe I thought of the reverse iteration as an option but it just seems like there's got to be an easier(read:elegant) solution. And as far as `DOMDocumentFragment`, it only has the `appendXML()` method which would fail on the first example replacement I put up because of the nested tags in the text.

Comment: No, it has `appendChild` as well, because it inherits that from `DOMNode` …

Comment: @CBRoe That's true, so how would I move the DOMNodeList from the $temp/$replacement `DOMNode` to the `DOMNodeFragment`, would I have to just iterate over all the child nodes and append them one at a time?  Or is there a faster way?  Again, if you want to put up an example, I'd be happy to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some conversation in the OP comments, I was able to come up with the following replacement strategy which remains performant and compatible with all of the examples I posed.

```
$temp = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$temp->loadHTML('<fubar id="replacement">'.$val.'</fubar>');
$replacement = $temp->getElementById('replacement');

// If element is a text node just add a new node with the value, otherwise if it's an element with child nodes, iterate over them adding them to a fragment which can be imported as a whole.
if ($replacement->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE || ($replacement->nodeValue && $replacement->childNodes->length === 1 && $replacement->childNodes->item(1) === NULL)) {
    // Text Node
    $new_node = $element->ownerDocument->createTextNode($replacement->nodeValue);
} else {
    // Node List
    $new_node = $element->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $children = $replacement->childNodes->length - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $children; $i++) {
        $child = $element->ownerDocument->importNode($replacement->childNodes->item($i), TRUE);
        $new_node->appendChild($child);
    }
}
$element->parentNode->replaceChild($new_node,$element);
unset($replacement);
unset($temp);
```

**--- N.B. ---**

I struggled a LOT with the iteration over childNodes.  I was able to see the childNodes existed in `$replacement` but they seemed to always be empty.

That is until I realized that the `documentFragment` needed to be created in the original element's doc rather than the temp one, AND the new child appended AFTER importing to the doc.

The root cause was that the child node (`$replacement->childNodes->item($i)`) couldn't be appended to a doc that it already existed in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your input, this is how I solved my similar problem, where I needed to strip all `//span[@class="scayt-misspell-word"]` and replace it with its content (which can be text, nodes, or any combination of those).
Note I used `HTML5DOMDocument` for preserving custom tags: https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php

```
$doc = new HTML5DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($oldText);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$body = $xpath->query('//body')->item(0);
while ($span = $xpath->query('//span[@class="scayt-misspell-word"]')
  ->item(0)) {
  $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
  foreach ($span->childNodes as $child) {
    $frag->appendChild($child);
  }
  $span->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $span);
}

$newText = $doc->saveHTML($body);
```